# Using Image Recognition

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

Is there any way of using Watsons image classifying abilities to extract information from an image of a document? Rather than simply classifying an image as a, b or c?

Answer (score 0):

### Visit [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/#classify_an_image) to learn more about **watson** `visual-recognition`

**Raw code (final code) :** ***#just for reference***, read how to create a classifier and implement of your own !

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from watson_developer_cloud import VisualRecognitionV3

test_url = 'https://url-to-ran-image.jpg'

visual_recognition = VisualRecognitionV3('2017-01-11', api_key='YOUR API KEY')


tree_path = join(dirname(__file__), '../resources/trees.zip')
with open(tree_path, 'rb') as images_file:
    tree_results = visual_recognition.classify(images_file=images_file,
                                              threshold=0.1,
                                              classifier_ids=[
                                                  'Carsvsmango_1479118188',
                                                  'default'])
    print(json.dumps(tree_results, indent=2))

url_result = visual_recognition.classify(images_url=test_url)
print(json.dumps(url_result, indent=2))

faces_result = visual_recognition.detect_faces(images_url=test_url)
print(json.dumps(faces_result, indent=2))

print(json.dumps(visual_recognition.list_classifiers(), indent=2))

file_path = join(dirname(__file__), '../some-random-text-image.png')
with open(file_path, 'rb') as image_file:
    text_results = visual_recognition.recognize_text(images_file=image_file)
    print(json.dumps(text_results, indent=2))

face_path = join(dirname(__file__), '../face.jpg')
with open(face_path, 'rb') as image_file:
    face_result = visual_recognition.detect_faces(images_file=image_file)
    print(json.dumps(face_result, indent=2))
```

### **Diagram that helps in understanding watson's recognition platform well.**

[image: Watson]